# Wordpress theme customisations

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I'm working on customising a Wordpress theme called BusinessFinder+. It seems like a really solid theme but I'm getting pressure from my client to make some difficult tweaks.

I'm sure there is a simple snippet for the functions.php file but my skills don't stretch that far.

I'm trying to change the placeholder text for the homepage seach form (just below the hero slider):
https://www.betauk.com/nebetasi/

The current text is "Search keywords", we need it to be "Search members".

Also, there's another search form layout here (on top of the hero image):
https://www.betauk.com/nebetasi/about-beta/

This has the same placeholder text problem, instead of "Search keywords", we need it to be "Search members".

I've tried a simple "str_replace" snippet but it doesn't touch what's in the search forms. I've tried a "str_replace" on other text sections of the homepage (for example) and it works.

Can anyone offer any tips?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to find the way to change your placeholder then you can do this by using jquery.

Please check it:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
 $('#searchinput-text').attr("placeholder","Search members");
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="s" id="searchinput-text" placeholder="Search keyword" class="searchinput" value="">
```

with using this code, your both search text box placeholder text will be changed.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you Ahmed, that's great. Just to double check, where should I put these snippets? In the header?

Comment: You should add jquery in footer before </body> tag.

Comment: That's beautiful, Ahmed. Thank you, thank you, thank you! Is there a way I can contact you directly about another customisation issue? Or at least find out how much it would cost me to get your help?

Comment: Yeah, sure @Hawkinsian. Glad it worked. You can also visit : [[Ask questions, get answers, no distractions]](((http://stackoverflow.com/tour))) to get more information about SO and support me as much as you can.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just go into where the form is (either in widgets or possibly in appearance->editor and amongst the files there) and find the form widget and edit the forms placeholder attribute?

```
<input type="text" name="s" id="searchinput-text" placeholder="Search keyword" class="searchinput" value="">
```

Comment: Thanks Jordano, but it's not an easily customiseable option and I've looked in the editor section. It's not there. It get's these form elements from much deeper inside the template files.